# Netbeans PHP Project Apache Setup -

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xdebug, netbeans-6.9

I've set up a project called testphp in Netbeans PHP. It has one file called Index.php. I've added  to the html and have tried both run and debug.

I receive the following message from Firefox:

> (URL:
>   http://localhost/TestPHP/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug)
>   Not Found: The requested URL /TestPHP/index.php was not found on this
>   server. http://localhost returns "It Works!"
>
> The virtual directory "TestPHP" does not appear to exist either. Can
>   someone suggest some pointers for tracking down the problem?
>
> Ubuntu : 10.10 Apache : 2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP : PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
>   with Suhosin-Patch Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

Comment: (added php hello world to the body of the text - the text editor here has removed the php tag!)

Answer (score 2):

Your project isn't actually being served by your local server.  The "It Works!" output is a default page your server is outputting because there are no actual files for it to serve.

The NetBeans "Local Web Site" project configuration assumes that your PHP sources will be stored in your local server's Web documents directory.

If you look at the [NetBeans docs](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#localServer), you'll see there's an option to make NetBeans automatically copy your project's files to the appropriate web server directory when you "Run" your project.