# Finding Tomcat Document Root

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7

I'm trying to test a php app I'm working on in my Netbeans environment, but I've been thus far unable to test it on the Tomcat server I have on my machine.
After doing some research on the problem, [I found this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207593/netbeans-php-project-apache-setup/5207651#5207651) which suggests that I need to copy my project files to the document root. The problem is, I can't seem to find the document root for my server.

What's the best way of locating the document root? I don't think I've changed the location from the default, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Further research has led me to find that Tomcat may not be the best server for a php app. I've since resolved my issue (but not the actual question here) but I figure I may as well leave this up in case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Tomcat is a **Servlet/JSP container** but not to be thought as a web server.

Based on your description, I took a wild guess that your project was created or later configured as "**Run As: Local Web Site (running on local web server)**".
FYI, other **Run As** methods shown (as of 7.4) below:

[image]

You mentioned

> I can't seem to find the document root for my server.

so the question from me is: *do you have a web server*, such as [Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/), *installed locally*!? If not, [you can get one here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/); I'd suggest picking the version identical to the deployment environment or at least close to it.

If local web server is installed and is functioning properly, you must have a working **DOCUMENT_ROOT**. To locate the path of **DOCUMENT_ROOT** (demonstrated w/ Apache httpd under Windows™):

1. Navigate to the installation directory (or folder, if you prefer) and you shall see a sub-directory named "**conf**".
2. In the *conf* directory look for a file called "**httpd.conf**" and open it w/ your favorite text editor.

   - Caveat: Normally there's only one site in the default configuration. Chances are it was installed before and multiple VirtualHost were created; if that's the case, you might need to look under "**conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**".
   - One more caveat: The value of the **DOCUMENT_ROOT** could be *relative*, you might need to *prepend* the installation path in order to use it somewhere else (NetBeans IDE in our case).
3. Search for the line that begins w/ "**DocumentRoot**", and the followed value is what you are looking for.
4. Use that value in your project, don't forget to click on "**Copy files from Sources Folder to another location**" first.

[image]

Futhermore, [there is a way](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/wa-quercus/) to make Tomcat to be able to interpret PHP scripts: [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) from [Caucho Technology](http://caucho.com/); although there's a catch - it doesn't support UTF-8 very well (較客氣的說法)!

I understand this is a 6-month old question, I hope the above information is still useful to you.